# Insert Datetime.now from asp.net into sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I'm trying to insert 'DateTime.Now' into sql column type of datetime but when insert is done in `sql` table date is OK! (exp: 2015-02-11) but time is stored as 00:00:00!!! I tried to many alternates.
this is my code:

```
sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@join_date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:m:s");
```

What am I missing???

Comment: Try..date time.now.to string("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're specifying a `SqlDbType` of `Date` - that doesn't have a time. So when the driver is converting the parameter value into the desired type, it's removing the time part.

You're *also* converting `DateTime.Now` into a string for no obvious reason... and doing so in a way which uses an odd and lossy time format (`h:m:s`, with no AM/PM designator). If you really *did* want to convert to a string, it would be better to use `HH:mm:ss` for the time specifier.

This line:

```
sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@join_date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd h:m:s");
```

should be:

```
sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@join_date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: yes-thanks! Dear Jon Skeet time portion was added in a later revise so I forgot to change the DBType and string conversion was one of my alternations. any way thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Jon's answer is fine, but also, you can make things easier like this:

```
sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@join_date", DateTime.Now);
```

It will automatically use the correct data type, based on the type of the value.

Also - You said you were calling this from ASP.Net.  In web applications, `DateTime.Now` is usually not appropriate - because it uses the time zone of the *server*, and it doesn't retain any offset information so it can be ambiguous during [daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) fall-back transitions.  I recommend storing UTC-based values in the database (`DateTime.UtcNow`).

If you feel that the server's local time zone is relevant in your use case, then consider switching your database column to the `datetimeoffset` type and using `DateTimeOffset.Now`.  That will avoid problems with DST transitions.

See also:  [The case against DateTime.Now](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/)